# AWS DynamoDB Scan filterExpression - simple number comparison

Tags: amazon-web-services, expression, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a simple dynamoDB scan with a filter expression ([documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.html))

This is my expression string:

```
"attribute_exists("my_db_key") AND ("my_db_key" = 1)"
```

This simply states:

**"If a value for my_db_key exists AND my_db_key EQUALS 1, return it in the results"**

However it does not work and I get a this error:

```
Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token: "1", near: "= 1)
```

I am aware that I can use an attribute value placeholder for values and then use that in the expression but I do not want to do this. And according to Amazon's documentation it is NOT required.

So how do I do this simple expression? Does anyone have an example or link to documentation? Amazon's documentation is unfortunately of no help.

*NOTE: I am implementing this with AWSDynamoDBScanInput on iOS but my issue here is to do with global expression syntax so it should not matter.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a placeholder and pass the value separately. Here's some  [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults) and a [Post from AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=163614)

Answer (score 5):

Your params need to look something like this (for the Node AWS library):

```
params = {
  "FilterExpression": 'attribute_exists("my_db_key") AND ("my_db_key" = :value)',
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":value": 1
  },
  // ...
};

docClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
  // Handle err or process data
})
```

For some languages, the parameters should look more like this:

```
{
  "FilterExpression": 'attribute_exists("my_db_key") AND ("my_db_key" = :value)',
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":value": {"N":1}
  },
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement something similar but get a syntax error. Not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: It should be `"ExpressionAttributeValues":{":value":{"N":1}}` (cc @KatharineOsborne)

Comment: You are correct. The Node library I'm using lets me exclude type identifiers.

Comment: The type identifiers are unnecessary when using the DocumentClient library.